# Subset pandas dataframe up to when condition is met the first time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have not had any luck accomplishing a task, where I want to subset a pandas dataframe up to a value, and grouping by their id. In the actual dataset I have several columns in between 'id' and 'status'

For example:

```
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'status': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    id  status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    1       1
6    1       1
7    2       0
8    2       0
9    2       0
10   2       0
11   2       1
12   2       0
13   2       1
```

The desired subset would be:

```
    id  status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    2       0
6    2       0
7    2       0
8    2       0
9    2       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` + `cumsum`:

```
df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)\
       .apply(lambda x: x[x.status.cumsum().cumsum().le(1)])\
       .reset_index(drop=1)
df

   id  status
0   1       0
1   1       0
2   1       0
3   1       0
4   1       1
5   2       0
6   2       0
7   2       0
8   2       0
9   2       1
```

---

Here's an alternative that performs a `groupby` to create a mask to be used as an indexer:

```
df = df[df.status.eq(1).groupby(df.id)\
          .apply(lambda x: x.cumsum().cumsum().le(1))]\
          .reset_index(drop=1)
df

   id  status
0   1       0
1   1       0
2   1       0
3   1       0
4   1       1
5   2       0
6   2       0
7   2       0
8   2       0
9   2       1
```

Comment: Thank you @COLDSPEED. Can you explain the use of .cumsum().cumsum() twice? I see the difference in output but don't understand it fully.

Comment: @DarenEiri I have to commend you on your MCVE, because of it I realised it was necessary. Say `status` is `0 0 0 1 0 1`. I need the first 4 rows, correct? The first `cumsum` gives `0 0 0 1 1 2`. Based on the `>= 1` (or `le(1)`) condition, it'll give me the first 5 rows, while I want 4. The second `cumsum` gives me `0 0 0 1 2 4`, and now `le(1)` gives me only the first 4 rows that I want.

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Thank you for your explanation. I had used a `cumsum` approach during my numerous failed attempts but the second `cumsum` with `le(1)` makes the difference!