# quick way to subset pandas dataframe up to when column condition is met the first time

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359858/subset-pandas-dataframe-up-to-when-condition-is-met-the-first-time)

I have a dataframe where I want rows for each id till status is 1 for first time. The solution presented in the above thread works perfectly but is very slow. I have 70,000 rows in my dataset.

My dataset:

```
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'status': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    id  status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    1       1
6    1       1
7    2       0
8    2       0
9    2       0
10   2       0
11   2       1
12   2       0
13   2       1
```

The desired subset I want is this:

```
    id  status
0    1       0
1    1       0
2    1       0
3    1       0
4    1       1
5    2       0
6    2       0
7    2       0
8    2       0
9    2       1
```

Tried the solution in the related thread:

```
lambda x: x.cumsum().cumsum().le(1)
```

works but that is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution.
This can be definitely improved, but it works.

```
df.groupby("id")['status'].apply(lambda x: x[:x.values.tolist().index(1) + 1]).swaplevel()
```

Explanation:

```
.apply(lambda x: x[:x.values.tolist().index(1) + 1])
```

This line is composed of two main components.

We look for first occurence of value 1 and get its index `x.values.tolist().index(1)`
Then we add 1 so we can include number that we found.
We slice everything from beginning to the end.

This is done for each id group.

**VERSION 2**

This version handles cases where there is no 1 found in group values:

```
def magic(x):
    values = x.values.tolist()
    if 1 in values:
        return x[:values.index(1) + 1]
    else:
        return x

df.groupby("id")['status'].apply(magic)
```

Comment: This is failing if i have id 3 that just has 0. In that case, I want 3,0 row but it gives error that 1 not found in list. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47359927/16591526) thread using [parallel-pandas](https://pypi.org/project/parallel-pandas/). Here is a usage example

```py
import pandas as pd
#pip install parallel-pandas
from parallel_pandas import ParallelPandas

#initialize parallel-pandas
ParallelPandas.initialize(n_cpu=8)

#p_apply is parallel analogue of apply method
df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)\
       .p_apply(lambda x: x[x.status.cumsum().cumsum().le(1)])\
       .reset_index(drop=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df[~df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['status'].apply(lambda s: s.shift().eq(1).cummax())]
```

Getting the `cummax` is probably faster than a `cumsum`

Or, assuming only 0/1 values:

```
df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.loc[:g['status'].idxmax()])
```

Comment: Thanks.. This works better but is still taking around 85 seconds ..something faster would be even better

Comment: How many groups do you have? Any chance you can provide some code to construct an object similar to yours for testing?

Comment: @PRData I meant some code to create an example with ~70K rows ;)

Comment: Cannot provide the real data but have many groups. around 24k..